# Detect that a Javascript file did not load (Facebook's JS file)

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

When a user comes to our site, if they've logged into our Facebook app, we want to show them the "logged-in" view for the app `showFacebook()`.  Otherwise, we want to display an option to login to the app or login to our site with a local account `showLogin()`.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : <cfif cgi.SERVER_NAME CONTAINS "dev">'460582120708297'<cfelse>'1422691834609812'</cfif>,
                status     : true, // check login status
                cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
                // Handle the results of logging in 
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    showFacebook();
                }
                else {
                    showLogin();
                }
            });

            // Check if the user is already logged into the Facebook app
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    showFacebook();
                } else {
                    showLogin();
                }
            });
        };

        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function(d){
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));
```

This works great most of the time. But, sometimes, neither `showFacebook()` nor `showLogin()` are firing. My guess is that these are users who are at work or at school, and their network admins have blocked Facebook.

How can I detect that the Facebook JS file (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js) is not loading?

Comment: 1. This code must be inserted right after the body tag. 2.Some browser extensions might block facebook script from loading

Answer (score 1):

Check if `window.FB` is defined. If not, the library didn't load.

```
if (window.FB) {
    // go for it
}
```

Comment: Where would I add this? The problem seems to be that fbAsyncInit is asynchronous. So, FB isn't defined until it runs, but it fails to run if the http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js is unreachable.

Comment: Ah, I see, I misunderstood how the library is defined. I thought it also set the value of `window.FB` but I guess it doesn't do that until it's loaded.

Comment: I was actually able to use your response to write a timeout.  See my answer. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I went with a variation on Doge's response:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

            // Show the login without the Facebook button if Facebook doesn't load in 5 seconds
            setTimeout(function(){
                if(!window.FB){
                    $("#facebook_login_area").hide();
                    showLogin();
                }   
            },5000);
});
```

I give the asynchronous call from Facebook 5 seconds to load.  If it hasn't loaded in that time, I display my `showLogin()` without the option to login to the Facebook app.